# What happen when two threads handled by two processors,trying to access single resource in heap at the same time?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

What happen when two separate threads handled by two processors, access same property in heap same time.It makes error or not?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554603/what-happen-when-two-or-more-thread-trying-access-single-resource

Answer (score 1):

It all happens down at the microelectronics level. Essentially the cache subsystems in the two processors have to negotiate with each other to decide which, if either, has the most recent copy of the resource, or fetch it from the DRAM of whichever processor has it. On Intel architectures this happens over an inter-chip network called QPI, on AMD architectures it's Hypertransport (may have a newer name now). Basically both architectures are NUMA - the DRAM is not directly accessible by all processors - but QPI / Hypertransport synthesise an SMP architecture - pretending that all DRAM is directly accessible by all processors. This is what your software  / OS experiences when it runs.

QPI and Hypertransport are pretty complicated, and invisible to software.